# How do I receive Super Sea Snails from Splatfest?

Tags: splatoon

I've played the last *Splatfest* (Spongebob vs Patrick) getting a *Champion* [rank](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Splatfest#Rank_System) but ending in the losing team. This should have awarded me 10 **Super Sea Snails**.
But I've got none yet.

How do I get my prize? Do I need a minimum level? Did I have to connect on a specific day to collect them?

Now there's a new Splatfest incoming, so I fear I've lost them forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive the *Super Sea Snails* once you start the game, right after *Callie and Marie*'s introduction. They reward you with the prize, then you'll receive it in the plaza.
If you wait too much to collect the Snails after a *Splatfest* and another one arrives, you'll eventually lose them forever.